# How do I use default props in a React component with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to React and I have a simple child-component. I want to set default props so if no prop is given when the component is called it uses whatever the defaults are set at. So far I have:

```
import React from 'react';

interface titleComponentProps {
  title?: string;
}

const titleComponentDefaults = ({
  title: "default title",
})

const titleComponent = ({
  title,
}: titleComponentProps) => {
  return <React.Fragment>{title}</React.Fragment>;
};

export default DynamicHelperText;
```

I am unclear as to how to have the default props appear in the component. Would anyone know the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to [pass a default value as you would any argument in a function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

```
const TitleComponent = ({
  title = 'Default Title',
}: TitleComponentProps) => {
  return <React.Fragment>{title}</React.Fragment>;
};
```

Your Prop type is correct as `title?: string` since the `?` indicates that you can omit that parameter when calling the component.